# Apache Velocity: Escape character not working

Tags: java, templates, velocity

I'm using Velocity to generate java code and I'm running into a problem with the following line in the template:

```
return Marshal$sdo.getName().dynamicSize(this);
```

with the desired output being:

```
return MarshalSomeClass.dynamicSize(this);
```

In this case the VLT is limited to "$sdo.getName()" but the trailing "." causes it not to evaluate the VLT portion.

When I try to escape the "." (e.g. `$sdo.getName()\.dynamicSize`) I get the following output:

```
return MarshalTestTypesFile\.dynamicSize(this);
```

I've tried assigning the "." to a VLT variable and wrapping it with curly braces, but then the curly braces are printed. I've tried `{$sdo.getName()}` and have the same problem. I've tried all the other tricks for escaping to no avail. Seems like it should be pretty simple, but I'm stumped. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the formal VTL notation with the braces:

```
return Marshal${sdo.getName()}.dynamicSize(this);
```

Comment: Jiminy christmas! After all that I was merely putting the opening brace in the wrong spot! Thanks!